# GameplayKit -[GKGraph dealloc]: crash on iOS9.2

Tags: ios, swift, gameplay-kit

I wrote a game called "Spiral" with Swift and GameplayKit.But when my `GKGridGraph` instance dealloc, the app always crash.This happens only on iOS9.2. I have test my code on iOS9.0, everything was all right. Here is the crash calling stack:

```
#0  0x0000000112e2546f in objc_loadWeakRetained ()
#1  0x000000011157ed38 in GKCGridGraph::~GKCGridGraph() ()
#2  0x000000011157ee4e in GKCGridGraph::~GKCGridGraph() ()
#3  0x000000011157c07e in -[GKGraph dealloc] ()
#4  0x0000000112e25afe in objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) ()
#5  0x000000010efa094a in @objc MazeMap.__ivar_destroyer ()
#6  0x0000000112e107bb in object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) ()
#7  0x0000000112e1b390 in objc_destructInstance ()
#8  0x0000000112e1b3c3 in object_dispose ()
#9  0x0000000111ac3d4d in -[UIResponder dealloc] ()
#10 0x0000000111713426 in -[SKNode dealloc] ()
#11 0x0000000112e25afe in objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) ()
#12 0x000000010ef8136a in @objc PlayerControlComponent.__ivar_destroyer ()
#13 0x0000000112e107bb in object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) ()
#14 0x0000000112e1b390 in objc_destructInstance ()
#15 0x0000000112e1b3c3 in object_dispose ()
#16 0x0000000112e25afe in objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) ()
#17 0x00000001109078c8 in -[__NSArrayI dealloc] ()
#18 0x0000000112e25afe in objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) ()
#19 0x0000000112e260b8 in (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) ()
#20 0x00000001153489ef in CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) ()
#21 0x000000011097ac84 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#22 0x000000011097a831 in __CFRunLoopDoTimer ()
#23 0x000000011093c241 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#24 0x000000011093b828 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#25 0x0000000115916ad2 in GSEventRunModal ()
#26 0x00000001118b6610 in UIApplicationMain ()
#27 0x000000010ef918ad in main at /Users/yangxiaoyu/Documents/Code/Spiral/Spiral/AppDelegate.swift:16
#28 0x0000000113cbe92d in start ()
#29 0x0000000113cbe92d in start ()
```

I use `GKGridGraph` in my `MazeModeScene` class:

```
private let MazeWidth: Int32 = 33
private let MazeHeight: Int32 = 33

private func tileAtRow(row: Int32, column col: Int32) -> TileType {
    return  TileType(rawValue: Maze[Int(row * MazeWidth + col)]) ?? .None
}

class MazeMap: SKNode {

    let width = MazeWidth

    let height = MazeHeight

    let pathfindingGraph: GKGridGraph = GKGridGraph(fromGridStartingAt: vector_int2(0, 0), width: MazeWidth, height: MazeHeight, diagonalsAllowed: false)

    var startPosition: GKGridGraphNode

    let shapeStartPositions: [GKGridGraphNode]

    init(size: CGSize) {

        var walls = [GKGridGraphNode]()
        var spawnPoints = [GKGridGraphNode]()
        startPosition = GKGridGraphNode(gridPosition: vector_int2(0, 0))

        for j in 0 ..< height {
            for i in 0 ..< width {
                let tile = tileAtRow(height - 1 - j, column: i)
                switch tile {
                case .Wall:
                    if let wall = pathfindingGraph.nodeAtGridPosition(vector_int2(i, j)) {
                        walls.append(wall)
                    }
                case .Portal:
                    if let portal = pathfindingGraph.nodeAtGridPosition(vector_int2(i, j)) {
                        spawnPoints.append(portal)
                    }
                case .Start:
                    startPosition = pathfindingGraph.nodeAtGridPosition(vector_int2(i, j))!
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        pathfindingGraph.removeNodes(walls)
        shapeStartPositions = spawnPoints

        super.init()

        addMagicRoads()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func pointForGridPosition(position: vector_int2) -> CGPoint {
        let center = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.midX, y: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.midY)
        let deltaX = (position.x - MazeWidth / 2) * mazeCellWidth
        let deltaY = (position.y - MazeHeight / 2) * mazeCellWidth
        return CGPoint(x: center.x + deltaX , y: center.y + deltaY)
    }

    func addMagicRoads() {
        // Generate maze.
        let graph = pathfindingGraph
        for j in 0 ..< height {
            for i in 0 ..< width {
                if graph.nodeAtGridPosition(vector_int2(i, j)) != nil {
                    let node = MagicRoad(graph: graph, position: vector_int2(i, j))
                    node.position = pointForGridPosition(vector_int2(i, j))
                    addChild(node)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried on the current iOS 9.3 beta?

Comment: @rickster Good idea! I hope this can help me :)

Answer (score 1):

As @rickster said, it doesn't crash on iOS 9.3 beta6.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in GKGridGraph dealloc in 9.2. I reported it to Apple who replied that it was a known bug. It was apparently fixed in 9.3 since the test case I sent to Apple now works.

Comment: Yeah, but I find it leaks in 9.3